# Parsing unicode characters without backslash using python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

Is there an easy way of parsing unicode characters like this u00e4 that does not have any backslash character using python3. I would like to replace the unicode sequence with the correct character instead. I have a text like the one below.

```
Hju00e4lper dig, Tru00e4ffa lu00e4kare, sjuksku00f6terskor och psykologer mm
```

I can of course use some kind of regex matching but are there an easier way of doing it using python3?

Comment: I think with corrupt data like this find/replace is the only option, with via regex or simple string processing.

Comment: Ideally you should tell the programmer which removed the backslash to correct it. Such bug can be abused (also for security). Get correct data, instead of hacking and having much more problems later. Else: use regular expression to add the backslash (you need to find good rules, in order not to overdo it). Easy to made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub` with a function to convert the digits to a character:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s='Hju00e4lper dig, Tru00e4ffa lu00e4kare, sjuksku00f6terskor och psykologer mm'
>>> re.sub('u([0-9a-f]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
'Hjälper dig, Träffa läkare, sjuksköterskor och psykologer mm'
```

Comment: Yes similar to what I created +1